# Power Query function for adding column sequence number for the same rows

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Is there a function for that, or how to make/add one?

Sorry, I am new to the DAX function.

Below is some function but don't know how to make Power Query function from that.

```
Sequence = 
VAR CurrentID = TableX[Order]
RETURN

CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( TableX ),
    FILTER ( 
        ALL( TableX ),
        CurrentID = TableX[IOrder]
    )
)
```

Should look in  Power query like this below.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Group By Order & Use Custom Column to Add Index Number.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorry, now a bit confused about how grouping with index can achieve this. Only want sequence as per example, when new value starts then sequence restarts from 1

Comment: You need `ID` column right ? Based on `Order` Column. How is your existing Table look like, what you have shared is the expected output. Please do let me know so that I can understand.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorry column name as ID is confusing,  ID is just name, sequence should be as per example.

Comment: Yeah that I have understood, basically you need the sequence in the `ID` Column

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Column name ( ID) can be any name , for example "Sequence"

Comment: see in **Power Query** you need to upload the table and do the requisite its not like **Power Pivot** `DAX` where you can apply a function and it will fill down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have tried,

• Select any cell in the table,

• From **Data** Tab, Under **Get & Transform Data Group**, Click **From Table/Range**

• This will import & open the table in **Power Query Editor**

• From **Home** Tab --> Under **Transform Group** --> Click **Group By**

• In **Group By** Window --> **New Column Name** --> **All** --> **Operation** --> **All Rows** --> **OK**

• From **Add Column** Tab --> Click on **Custom Column**
• **New Column Name** --> **Index**

• **Custom Column Formula**

```
= Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"ID",1,1)
```

• Press **Ok.**

• Now click on the drop down in **Index** column & expand, select only **ID**

[image: STEP_4]

• Remove the column Named **All**,

• From **Home** Tab --> Click on **Closed & Load To**

• You shall get an Import Data**strong text** Window --> Select either **Existing Worksheet** with the cell reference you want to have the output table or **New Worksheet**. Press Ok.

Or you can paste this `M-Code` in the **Advance Editor** in **Power Query Editor** -> Note that the Table Name should be **TableX** or if you have something else you can change it in the code.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableX"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Order"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Order=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"ID",1,1)),
    #"Expanded Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", {"ID"}, {"ID"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Index",{"ID", "Order"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

[image: SOLUTION]